# append the matched text to the line

Tags: grep

Lets say I have a file called sample.txt which contains

```
ab
bc
ac
```

`grep -E "^b|c$" sample.txt` gives me output as

```
bc
ac
```

Now  I want the filter string to be added to the output.
I want the output as

```
bc,b
ac,c
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do it in `grep`, but in GNU awk you could do `gawk 'match($0,/^b|c$/) {printf "%s,%s\n", $0, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' sample.txt`

Comment: @steeldriver, that's standard `awk` syntax, not GNU specific.

Answer (score 2):

***perl*** alternative solution:

```
perl -nle 'print "$_,$&" if /^b|c$/' sample.txt
```

The output:

```
bc,b
ac,c
```

---

- `$_` - refers to the string the regular expression is matching against
- `$&` - returns the entire matched substring

---

With external *Perl* script:

***my.pl*** :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    chomp $_;
    print "$_,$&\n" if /(^b|c$)/;
}
```

*Usage*:

```
perl my.pl sample.txt
```

Comment: Don't want to run it from Command line. What do I need to change to save this in a file ?

Comment: @Thomas, `perl -nle 'print "$_,$&" if /^b|c$/' sample.txt > result.txt`

Comment: Thanks, I mean instead of running it from Command line, I want to save this as .pl file. So that I can execute the file separately.

Comment: @Thomas, see my update

Answer (score 2):

With `pcregrep`:

```
$ pcregrep --om-separator=, -o -o1 -o2 '^(b).*|.*(c)$' sample.txt
bc,b
ac,c
```